# Change Windows root dynamically, Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8

I want to Switch From `Navigation Controller` to `RevealViewController`,

Like, `Navigation Controller (AgreementVC -> loginVC ) ->  RevealViewController`

For this-
I have set a `UINavigationController` as root on window

and, after login , I am setting another controller (`Reveal`) as root on Window.

In `Swift` the code is executing perfectly but not reflecting any result (the root is not changing).

CODE

```
func switchToRevealView()
{
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootRevealController

}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the `RevealViewController` already presented? This is how I usually switch to a new root view controller:

```
viewController.presentViewController(drawerController, animated: true) {
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??
    if window?.rootViewController != drawerController {
        window?.rootViewController = drawerController
    }
}
```

where `viewController` is the one currently active, and `drawerController` is the new one I am showing and setting as root as soon as it's been presented.